# Using python module

Tags: python, module

I have a problem with using python module inside another one. The use case is as follows:

Consider the following scenario. The error was commented accordingly.

In file A.py:

```
import B

...
...
```

In file B.py:

```
import C
import A

c_func = C.func1() # works perfectly
a_func = A.func2() # Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'func2' 

...
...
```

In file C.py:

```
...
...
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us the code for A.py which defines `func2`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a circular import. In general, they don't work.

See [How can I have modules that mutually import each other?](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other) in the FAQ for an explanation, and some different ways to solve it. There's also a [Circular Imports](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports) section on Fredrik Lundh's effbot site. But briefly:

- `A` starts executing.
- `A` reaches the `import B`.
- `B` starts executing.
- `B` reaches the `import A`. Since `A` already exists, this does nothing. Whatever code in `A` wasn't run yet—like the definition for `A.func2`—still hasn't run.
- `B` tries to use `A.func2`, which hasn't been defined yet, so you get an error.

(Even more briefly, but less accurately: `B` depends on `A`, which depends on `B`, which means `B` can't run until `B` runs. This may help you get an intuitive understanding of the problem, which may help you understand the more complete/accurate explanation above.)

What you probably want to do is move the code in `A` that `B` needs into a separate module, which both `A` and `B` can import, which won't need to import either `A` or `B`. That's not the *only* possible solution (see the FAQ entry for two other ideas), but when it's possible to do this cleanly, it's hard to beat it. (Without actual code, it's hard to give a more specific answer than that.)

Comment: But it *can* work so long as the function is called after the import finishes, right?

Comment: @mhlester: Yes. One of the possible solutions suggested in the FAQ is to move all of `B`'s top-level code into a function, and have `A` call that function only after it's defined whatever that function needs. And another possible solution is to move the `import B` farther down in `A` until after `func2` has been defined.